# SQL Server table to xml

Tags: sql-server

this time i have question how to convert MSSQL table to XML

My source SQL table:

```
+-----------+-----------------+
|atributname|atributvalue     |
+-----------+-----------------+
|phone      |222              |
|param4     |bbbbcdsfceecc    |
|param3     |bbbbcdsfceecc    |
|param2     |bbbbcdsfccc      |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

Expected result sample:

```
<items>
<phone>222</phone>
<prama4>bbbbcdsfceecc</param4>
<param3>bbbbcdsfceecc</param3>
<param2>bbbbcdsfccc</param2>
</items>
```

I tried lot of variations of the following query

```
SELECT atributname,atributvalue  
FROM sampletable FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT ('items');
```

but results are not good :( should be exactly like in "Expected result sample"

any help

ps
Script to create sampletable:

```
create table sampletable
(atributname varchar(20),
atributvalue varchar(20))


insert into  sampletable (atributname,atributvalue) 
values ('phone','222');

insert into  sampletable (atributname,atributvalue) 
values ('param4','bbbbcdsfceecc');

insert into  sampletable (atributname,atributvalue) 
values ('param3','bbbbcdsfceecc');

insert into  sampletable (atributname,atributvalue) 
values ('param2','bbbbcdsfccc');
```

Comment: could you please be more specific than "results are not good"

Comment: I get
<items><atributname>phone</atributname><atributvalue>222</atributvalue><atributname>param4</atributname><atributvalue>bbbbcdsfceecc</atributvalue><atributname>param3</atributname><atributvalue>bbbbcdsfceecc</atributvalue><atributname>param2</atributname><atributvalue>bbbbcdsfccc</atributvalue></items>

but i need
<items>
<phone>222</phone>
<prama4>bbbbcdsfceecc</param4>
<param3>bbbbcdsfceecc</param3>
<param2>bbbbcdsfccc</param2>
</items>

Answer (score 2):

That's not how `FOR XML` works.  It's *columns* that get turned into XML elements, not rows.  In order to obtain the expected result, you would need to have columns named `phone`, `param4`, and so on - not rows with these values in `attributename`.

If there are specific elements you want in the XML, you could perform a pivot on the data first, then use `FOR XML`.

Example of a pivot would be:

```
SELECT [phone], [param2], [param3], [param4]
FROM
(
    SELECT attributename, attributevalue
    FROM attributes
) a
PIVOT
(
    MAX(attributevalue)
    FOR attributename IN ([phone], [param2], [param3], [param4])
) AS pvt
FOR XML ROOT('items')
```

Of course the aggregate will only work if `attributevalue` is a numeric data type.  If it's a character-type column, then you'll have some trouble with the pivot, as there are no built-in string aggregates in SQL server AFAIK...

Comment: Thats very good idea, but there is a problem if number of items increase for exmaple new items  > param5 , param6. In pivot there is static information about row included [phone], [param2], [param3], [param4].

Comment: @wicherqm: Yes, that's one of many reasons why the EAV model is widely considered to be a "last resort" design.  Do you really need to be storing your data as arbitrary attribute-value pairs instead of as a traditional normalized relational schema?

Comment: i now,but i need simplicity for end users, this is why  
ps solution below

Answer (score 0):

ok
finally i have done this in several ways,
but this is **simplest** version suitable for medium  dataset

```
declare @item  nvarchar(max)

set @item= (SELECT '<' + atributname +'>' +
            cast(atributvalue as nvarchar(max)) +'</' + atributname +'>'
            FROM sampletable FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT ('items'));

select replace(replace(@item,'&lt;','<'),'&gt;','>')
```